# Can't find resource for bundle 'ExceptionMessages_en_US', key in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new again to Java.  Can't say I remember using a ResourceBundle.   I am getting the exception Can't find resource for bundle 'ExceptionMessages_en_US', key.

Here is my ListResourceBundle class:

(I took the example straight from the JavaDoc and modified it with my own strings)

```
public class ExceptionMessages extends ListResourceBundle {

@Override
protected Object[][] getContents() {
     return new Object[][] {

             {"interfaceCount", "Device should have 1 interface."},
             {"epCount", "Device should have 3 endpoints."},
             {"noIntrIn", "Device does not have an interrupt input endpoint."},
             {"noBulkIn", "Device does not have a bulk input endpoint."},
             {"noBulkOut", "Device does not have a bulk output endpoint."},
             {"openFailed", "A call to deviceOpen has failed."},
             {"claimFailed", "A call to claimInterface has failed."},
             {"startSessionFailed", "Start USB Session has failed."},
             {"sessionNotStarted", "USB Session not started."},
             {"bulkTxError", "Bulk endpoint transmit error."},
             {"intrRxError", "Interrupt endpoint recieve error."},


        };  
}

}
```

I also tried naming the class ExceptionMessages_en_US with no luck

I get the resource bundle like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ExceptionMessages");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

    int i = 0;
    i++;


}
```

I also tired:

```
 public void Test()
 {
    try
    {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ExceptionMessages",new Locale("en", "US"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

    int i = 0;
    i++;


}
```

But still get the exception.

What am I missing?  I am sure it is something dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the full package containing ExceptionMessages.

Example:

```
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.mycomp.ExceptionMessages");
```